# OLTP Performance Issue with Netezza

Tags: migration, database-migration, netezza

We recently migrated our database from Oracle to Netezza . Our's is mainly an OLAP database but a part of it is OLTP which populates few tables ( Front end application) . These real-time tables will get joined with few history tables and generates reports.  We are satisfied with the performance of the OLAP part of it , but the OLTP has a major performance issue. What are the ways to improve OLPT in Netezza ?  Or is there any design approach to maintain OLTP separately ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend using `Netezza` for OLTP however we get into situations where the data is so large that we don't have another choice.  In those circumstances you can do some tuning to speed things up.

1. Make sure that your table has good `distribution` if you can't find a good column to `distribute on` then `distribute on random`
2. Add `organize` to the table on the key your OLTP operations are based on
3. Make sure your key is a distributable datatype `Integer`,`Date`

Alternatively you may consider a hybrid design

1. Do your OLTP operations for your web application in `SQL Server` or `Postgres`
2. ETL changes back to `Netezza` every few minutes or hours.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main considerations for performance with a parallel system: even distribution of data; and collocation of data that will be joined. The first point was already addressed: choose a good partitioning key that will give you good, even distribution of data.

As to my second point, if data is going to be joined (say for update), there has to be little or no data movement. Making sure this is true will reduce data traffic. The best way to ensure data is collocated is to use the same partitioning key. The same key will always hash to the same node; the same node means no traffic to do the join. For example, say you have Cust (CNo), Order (Ono), Order Item (Ono, INo),and Product (PNo). The primary keys are in parentheses. If you use the above as partitioning keys, the data will NOT be collocated. If, however, you use CNo in Cust, the fk CNo in Order, and put a redundant fk of CNo in Order Item, all as the partitioning keys, they will be collocated. Product cannot be collocated but it doesn't need to be; it is usually not that large and it would make no sense to put a CNo in Product.

NOSQL does not allow joins because it cannot ensure collocation of join data (there are other reasons as well). In NOSQL data will be distributed over a wide array of nodes.

The two great performance killers are sorts and cartesian products. Make sure these do not exist in the data being joined on Netezza.